# Can't save Android XML file with custom component

Tags: android, android-widget, android-xml

I created Android XML lay out with some custom components. But when I am saving the XML file I get error. Since this is my fist time with custom components (widgets) I have no idea why am I getting this error. 
This is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp">

  <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="46dp"/>
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="100dp"/>
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/> 


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the error I get. **I must say that there is no such a  resource value in R.java file**

> error! NotFoundException: Could not
>   resolve resource value: 0x7F020009.
>
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   Could not resolve resource value:
>   0x7F020009.   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:546)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeResources.getDrawable(BridgeResources.java:131)
>     at
>   kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.initResourcesIfNecessary(WheelView.java:427)
>     at
>   kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.calculateLayoutWidth(WheelView.java:482)
>     at
>   kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.onMeasure(WheelView.java:518)
>     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:619)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:280)
>     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
>     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
>     at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
>     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.computeLayout(Bridge.java:443)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createLegacySession(LayoutLibrary.java:404)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:285)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1506)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1312)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1043)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onXmlModelChanged(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1005)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.xmlModelChanged(LayoutEditor.java:303)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractStructuredModel.fireModelChanged(AbstractStructuredModel.java:553)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractStructuredModel.internalModelChanged(AbstractStructuredModel.java:887)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractStructuredModel.changedModel(AbstractStructuredModel.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DOMModelImpl.changedModel(DOMModelImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:803)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.uimodel.UiElementNode.setPropertyValue(UiElementNode.java:1885)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.CanvasViewInfo.setPropertyValue(CanvasViewInfo.java:320)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.PropertySheetEntry.valueChanged(PropertySheetEntry.java:782)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.PropertySheetEntry.setValue(PropertySheetEntry.java:723)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.PropertySheetEntry.applyEditorValue(PropertySheetEntry.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.PropertySheetEntry$1.applyEditorValue(PropertySheetEntry.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellEditor$1.run(CellEditor.java:333)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellEditor.fireApplyEditorValue(CellEditor.java:331)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.ui.EditableDialogCellEditor.handleDefaultSelection(EditableDialogCellEditor.java:264)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.ui.EditableDialogCellEditor$1.widgetDefaultSelected(EditableDialogCellEditor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:119)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)

Please help me to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you name your file like mylayout.xml? Then you forgot -> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> at the start of the xml file and declaring the namespace in the first layout element -> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Fixed the layout so the xml start is actually visible :)

Comment: Did the fix with "xmlns:android..." work now? Maybe you should also clean the Project and build it again.
Is there a WheelView component in the package "kankan.wheel.widget"?

Comment: It's main.xml. I have declare the namespace. When I remove all three custom componets (WheelView) it gives no error.

Comment: @rainer : to be clear,I fixed the layout of the question, the namespace was there all along, but @chrishi 's formatting on SO was skipping it.

Comment: Is kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView inside the project you are using, otherwise you need to add it as a library. Also eclipse is sometimes really bad at sorting itself out, cleaning, deleting and reimporting project and opening and closing usually fix things for me.

Comment: I add the Kankan.widget.WheelView to my project. I cleaned it but nothing correct my problem.

Comment: can we see the Kankan.widget.WheelView.java file...? may be problem occures there...!!

Comment: Shall I post it here ? It has 800+ lines of codes. Since I am new to this forum I do not know whether I can do it.

Comment: There were some issues in importing resources to my project. I have solve it with your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a resource that is not found. It could be e.g. the `@drawable/layout_bg` you're using?

If that's not it, take a look at these two lines:

```
initResourcesIfNecessary(WheelView.java:427) 
calculateLayoutWidth(WheelView.java:482)
```

You're calling something there that is requesting a Resource that is not there (an Id, a drawable, etc etc).

Comment: If this was the problem then it wouldn't work when he takes out his custom components.

Comment: I have add layout_bg to the drawable folder and it is in the R.java file.

Comment: @stealthcopter : yep, but I hadn't read the comment when I posted that. So the problem should be in the initResourcesIfnecessary in that WheelView.java file.

Comment: There were some issues in importing resources to my project. I have solve it with your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem all I had to do is remove the following import:

```
import kankan.wheel.R; // remove this line
```

which gets added automatically when you copy and paste the code from the sample demo

[Remove the line highlighted in this screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF4C4.jpg)

Comment: this kind of issue may have multiple root causes, one root cause not mentioned here is to do with accessing resources in custom view initialization code - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543855/resourcesnotfoundexception-in-graphical-layout-adt-preview-but-app-actually-wo/17742353#17742353

Answer (score 1):

Every thing is correct. Please check the image format for **layout_bg** in drawable folder.
Supported formats:

1.jpg
2.png
3.bmp

(eg: Android accept .jpg, not .jpeg).

Comment: It is a custom layout. Not an image.

Comment: What is in that custom layout?

Comment: This is the code in the custom layout. 

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <gradient  
  android:startColor="#FF000000"
  android:centerColor="#FF000000"
  android:endColor="#FF777777"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>

By the way I have solved my problem. There were some issues in importing resources to my project. Thank for the Help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by `"try-catching"` the resources access in the method

```
     initResourcesIfNecessary
```

I understand that it is not the ideal solution, but at least now i can edit my layouts in design time.

The modified method is below

```
        private void initResourcesIfNecessary() {


    if (centerDrawable == null) {
        try {
            centerDrawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wheel_val);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            centerDrawable = null;
        }
    }

    if (topShadow == null) {
        try {
            topShadow = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, SHADOWS_COLORS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            topShadow = null;
        }
    }

    if (bottomShadow == null) {
        try {
            bottomShadow = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, SHADOWS_COLORS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            bottomShadow = null;
        }
    }
    try {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wheel_bg);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        setBackgroundResource(0);
    }
}
```