# Resources$NotFoundException in Graphical Layout ADT preview (but app actually Works)

Tags: android, exception, layout, adt

My problem is that loading an array of strings defined in XML works in the app but will result in an error in the ADT Graphical Layout preview.

Now I can't see any graphics in the Graphical Layout because of this error, and it's difficult to work with other graphics.
But the view is loading and displaying the strings fine if I build and run my app.

So I suppose my code is correct but either:

- I am missing some limitations of the Graphical Layout preview and some workaround
- or perhaps I'm missing something obvious and doing things wrong even if it seems to work in the app

I have a custom view where I get an array defined by me in an array.xml file.

```
public class ScoreTable extends View {
  [...]
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    [...]
    int score_vals[] = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.score_vals);
    [...]
  }
  [...]
}
```

My array is defined in res/values/array.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="score_vals">
        <item >10</item>
        <item >20</item>
        <item >50</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Graphical Layout is blank and says:

```
Int array resource ID #0x7f050000
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

But of course I have "public static final int score_vals=0x7f050000;" in R.java!

The details of this error are in a 50-deep stack, but resumes to this:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Int array resource ID #0x7f050000
    at android.content.res.Resources.getIntArray(Resources.java:405)
    at com.threecats.poker.ScoreTable.onDraw(ScoreTable.java:53)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
[...]
```

So, should getResources().getXXXArray() work in the context of a ADT Graphical Layout preview?

I would like to mention that I tried with both "array" and "array-integer" in the XML, and both work in the app but not in the preview.
Also I tried to save the Context from the constructor of the view in a private Context member... didn't help either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is alright but unfortunately there are still some bugs in ADT plugin and there is one of them. Layout Editor has troubles with rendering custom views. I had the same issue and the only workout I have found is checking [View.isInEditMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode()) and initializing int array in some other way but not from resources. So your code will look like this:

```
int score_vals[];
if (isInEditMode()) {
    score_vals = { 10, 20, 50 };
} else {
    score_vals = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.score_vals);
}
```

And by the way don't create or load any resources in your `onDraw` methods. I suppose `getResources().getIntArray` uses some sort of caching but anyway your perfomance may suffer.

Comment: thanks! I made the changes and now I get the data in the Constructor, that was loaded by the Activity like this: `gameData = ((FooActivity)context).gameData;` - but ADT now says `Error: ScoreTable failed to instantiate.` `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to com.foo.FooActivity` - so it seems the Context is stubbed and this causes all the errors in the preview. I seem to not have any other choice than to use `isInEditMode()` and replicate the XML values in the code for the preview... yuck!

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of a workaround whereby you have to hijack android's own attributes to get access to resources in the designer.

The following should provide the idea, but you would have to find a native android property of type int[]

#### This custom view XML should render in the graphical layout preview while using resources

```
<!-- Could override individual attributes here too rather than using a style -->
<com.github.espiandev.showcaseview.ShowcaseView
     style="@style/ShowcaseView"/>
```

#### styles.xml - Style specifying some of the resources to use

```
<style name="ShowcaseView" parent="match_fill">
    <!--# Cling drawable -->
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/cling</item>
    <!--# Title #-->
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/showcase_title</item>
    <!--# Description #-->
    <item name="android:description">@string/showcase_description</item>
    <!--# Button Text #-->
    <item name="android:text">@string/ok</item>
    <item name="sv_titleTextColor">#33B5E5</item>
    <item name="sv_detailTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#3333B5E5</item>
    <item name="sv_buttonBackgroundColor">#3333B5E5</item>
    <item name="sv_buttonForegroundColor">#33B5E5</item>
</style>
```

#### attrs.xml - Custom attribute definition compatible with design-time preview

```
<!-- The android attrs assume the corresponding android format / data type --> 
<declare-styleable name="ShowcaseView">
    <!--# Cling drawable -->
    <attr name="android:src"/>
    <!--# Title #-->
    <attr name="android:contentDescription"/>
    <!--# Description #-->
    <attr name="android:description"/>
    <!--# Button Text #-->
    <attr name="android:text"/>
    <attr name="sv_backgroundColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="sv_detailTextColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="sv_titleTextColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="sv_buttonBackgroundColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="sv_buttonForegroundColor" format="color|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

#### ShowcaseView.java - Using the custom attributes in the custom view

```
public ShowcaseView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, R.styleable.CustomTheme_showcaseViewStyle);
}

public ShowcaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.styleable.CustomTheme_showcaseViewStyle);
}

public ShowcaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // Get the attributes for the ShowcaseView
    final TypedArray styled = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ShowcaseView, 0, 0);
    showcase = styled.getDrawable(R.styleable.ShowcaseView_android_src);
    titleText = styled.getString(R.styleable.ShowcaseView_android_contentDescription);
    subText = styled.getString(R.styleable.ShowcaseView_android_description);
    buttonText = styled.getString(R.styleable.ShowcaseView_android_text);
    backColor = styled.getInt(R.styleable.ShowcaseView_sv_backgroundColor, Color.argb(128, 80, 80, 80));
    detailTextColor = styled.getColor(R.styleable.ShowcaseView_sv_detailTextColor, Color.WHITE);
    titleTextColor = styled.getColor(R.styleable.ShowcaseView_sv_titleTextColor, Color.parseColor("#49C0EC"));
    styled.recycle();
    // Now make use of the fields / do further initialization ..
}
```

Comment: this is not a workaround but exactly how the base `View` class works - and other android framework views. the problem is that even using this method, one still cannot retrieve an int array resource while in edit mode as `TypedArray` doesn't have a method for that kind of operation.