# pass in a layout resource using custom attributes for a custom view

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, custom-controls

I would like to specify a child layout for a custom view in XML, analogously to the layout attribute of the include element:

```
<include layout="@layout/all_apps_cling"
         android:id="@+id/all_apps_cling"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Furthermore, I need the custom view to render at design-time in Eclipse or IntelliJ graphical layout preview

#### Using attr name="android:layout" does not work

[at least not in graphical layout preview]

attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="ShowcaseView">
    <attr name="android:layout"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

usecase.xml

```
<com.github.espiandev.showcaseview.ShowcaseView
    style="@style/ShowcaseView"/>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ShowcaseView" parent="match_fill">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/handy</item>
</style>
```

ShowcaseView.java

```
public ShowcaseView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, R.styleable.CustomTheme_showcaseViewStyle);
}

public ShowcaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.styleable.CustomTheme_showcaseViewStyle);
}

public ShowcaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // Get the attributes for the ShowcaseView
    final TypedArray styled = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ShowcaseView, 0, 0);
    TypedValue handLayout = null;
    // Not sure if should be using .getValue in the first place
    // But there is no method TypedValue.getLayout or such 
    if (styled.getValue(R.styleable.ShowcaseView_android_layout, handLayout)) {
        // Does not reach here
    } else {
        // Reaches here instead i.e. getValue failed
    }
    styled.recycle();
}
```

#### Any solutions?

And I cannot use `<attr name="linkedLayout" format="reference"/>`, because I need it to work in the graphical layout preview - see the problem of accessing resources in the designer [Resources$NotFoundException in Graphical Layout ADT preview (but app actually Works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543855/resourcesnotfoundexception-in-graphical-layout-adt-preview-but-app-actually-wo/17742353#17742353)

Comment: did you try: <ShowcaseView ...><include ...></ShowcaseView>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to place your layout in master layout file:

```
<ShowcaseView ...>
    <include .../>
</ShowcaseView>
```

of course you can also add children directly instead of include tag:

```
<ShowcaseView ...>
    <Button .../>
    ...
    <Button .../>
</ShowcaseView>
```